# Where are $_SESSION variables stored?

Tags: php

Are `$_SESSION` variables stored on the client or the server?

Comment: on the server where you run the php application, for specific path you have to check with phpinfo()

Answer (score 197, accepted):

The location of the `$_SESSION` variable storage is determined by PHP's `session.save_path` configuration. Usually this is `/tmp` on a Linux/Unix system. Use the `phpinfo()` function to view your particular settings if not 100% sure by creating a file with this content in the `DocumentRoot` of your domain:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Here is the link to the PHP documentation on this configuration setting:

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path

Comment: For mac users with empty `session.save_path` (`session_save_path() == ""`, session.save_path -> no value on `phpinfo()`) it is still _"/tmp"_ but in macos way: **"/var/tmp"**. For me session files prefixed with "sess_".

Answer (score 148):

As mentioned already, the contents are stored at the server. However the session is identified by a session-id, which is stored at the client and send with each request. Usually the session-id is stored in a cookie, but it can also be appended to urls. (That's the `PHPSESSID` query-parameter you some times see)

Comment: +1 because you've implied that cookies do not store the contents of $_SESSION (these contents are stored on the server, so are not vulnerable to modification by the client)

Comment: Excellent answer! I was searching for the question: "Why do sessions expire after deleting browser cache?". And you saved my day.

Comment: server create file sess_7nu9p0fvidvva6ouaugqcc8292 аnd on browser alert(getCookie('PHPSESSID'));//7nu9p0fvidvva6ouaugqcc8292

Comment: Plus1 - For answering the question:" ...stored on the client or the server?"

Answer (score 24):

They're generally stored on the server. Where they're stored is up to you as the developer. You can use the `session.save_handler` configuration variable and the [`session_set_save_handler`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) to control how sessions get saved on the server. The default save method is to save sessions to files. Where they get saved is controlled by the `session.save_path` variable.

Answer (score 21):

One addition: It should be noted that, in case "/tmp" is the directory where the session data is stored (which seems to be the default value), the sessions will not persist after reboot of that web server, as "/tmp" is often purged during reboot. The concept of a client-wise persistence stands and falls with the persistence of the storage on the server - which might fail if the "/tmp" directory is used for session data.

Answer (score 14):

On Debian (isn't this the case for most Linux distros?), it's saved in /var/lib/php5/. As mentioned above, it's configured in your php.ini.

Answer (score 14):

I am using Ubuntu and my sessions are stored in /var/lib/php5.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I wanted. Yeah, if they weren't in the usual spot, I'll need to crack open the INIs, but I just wanted to know "Hey, where are the sessions _usually_ stored?" /var/lib/php/sessions/ it is.

Answer (score 8):

As Mr. Taylor pointed out this is usually set in php.ini.  Usually they are stored as files in a specific directory.

Answer (score 7):

For ubuntu 16.10 are sessions save in /var/lib/php/session/...

Answer (score 2):

In my Ubuntu machine sessions are stored at

```
/var/lib/php/sessions
```

and you have to `sudo ls` in this directory only `ls` it will throw

> ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied

And on my Windows Wamp server php sessions are stored in

```
C:\wamp64\tmp
```

and if you install standalone php on windows then there is no value set by default

```
session.save_path => no value => no value
```

Answer (score 1):

How does it work? How does it know it's me?

Most sessions set a user-key(called the sessionid) on the user's computer that looks something like this: 765487cf34ert8dede5a562e4f3a7e12. Then, when a session is opened on another page, it scans the computer for a user-key and runs to the server to get your variables.

If you mistakenly clear the cache, then your user-key will also be cleared. You won't be able to get your variables from the server any more since you don't know your id.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP session which is accessible via the global variable `$_SESSION` is stored on the **server** as files by default. Also the reference to it (called `session_id`) is stored on client side as browser cookies. If either of this is deleted, then the session becomes invalid.

You can change the storage to database/Redis/memcache etc. using [PHP Custom Session Handlers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php). Also there are extensions available for different storage like sqlite, memcache and memcached.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers above are opaque. In my opinion the author of this question simply wants to know where session variables are stored by default. According to this:https://canvas.seattlecentral.edu/courses/937693/pages/10-advanced-php-sessions they are simply **stored on the server by default**. Hopefully, others will find this contribution meaningful.