# Where is $_SESSION data stored and when it gets deleted?

Tags: php, session, global-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are $_SESSION variables stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454635/where-are-session-variables-stored)

I'm using this to store some data across page requests (state of two fields from a search form):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = $_POST;
```

I was wondering where are sessions stored? And when do they get deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are stored on the php server, and get deleted after a certain timeout when the server hasn't had a request from the associated client. The timeout is configurable in php.ini or [directly from your script](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php#63837).

Answer (score 3):

They are stored in [`session_save_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php). When the session is deleted (after [`session_destroy`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) or [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)), the tmp file is erased and then the space on the HD is reclaimed.

Comment: So if I don't call session_destroy, they will be stored there forever?

Comment: @Emma nope, sessions are usually stored in a temporary directory that gets frequently cleaned by the server. The details vary from OS to OS.

Comment: @Emma See [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)