# How the a webpage will knows that session is set or not?

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are $_SESSION variables stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454635/where-are-session-variables-stored)

When ever we working with session, we need to start the session in each page. now suppose i have set the session in `1.php` now redirecting to `2.php`, in 2.php page i am starting the session again there is no any link between `1.php` and `2.php`. `2.php` is not knowing what is the `session id` of `1.php`.

Now my question is How this `2.php` is getting the same `session id` started by `1.php`. Where this session is stored? how it is working?

Here we are not passing any parameter from 1.php to 2.php, as Frederick Marcoux is saying SESSION_START() is IGNORED by 2.php. So how 2.php will get to know that session is already running.

if it is on server side,then in case of multiple session  then how will it identify which session is for which request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way....

When someone accesses your 1.php page, the session_start() on the top of the page initiates an action on your server (hosting) and unique session id is generated.

Then it is attached to every page (url) on your server (under the same domain) (i.e.: 2.php or 3.php) and if these pages have the session_start() function present, the SID is available for the scripts (on those pages) and can be accessed and verified.

If the SID on your page 3.php is matching the one created/generated by the same user when he/she accessed the page 1.php then you know that this page is being accessed by the same person and do something else for them which you would not do for a visitor who got directly to the page 3.php and did not obtain the necessary SID for example.

The SID is passed from the server to your browser and kept as cookie until it is cleared or it expires.

( *...did I diluted it down to much ?*  :)

Comment: This thing looks like possible.But are you sure session id is attach to all the url, who will control it?

Comment: The session ID if auto-generated on the sever side is controlled by the server. Once it is stored into the visitor's browser it can be considered as a secret sign when the visitor is accessing other pages under the same domain. Of course you as a programmer can manipulate the session ID, its location, content, availability etc. Please see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_session.html

Comment: Thanks this gave me clear idea how its working.

Answer (score 1):

The session are Cookie based. When you start a session on one page, it will get an ID. This ID will be the same until you make a `session_destroy()` and you start a new session with `session_start()`.

#### Why is that way?

Because more than one page may use the same session ID for some user logging or tracking.

#### What does `session_start()` on `2.php`

It's simply ignored by the server. If you check your PHP log, you will see a thing like that:

```
SESSION_START() IGNORED. A SESSION HAS BEEN ALREADY STARTED.
```

---

I had the same question 3 months ago, but not on this website.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `session_save_path()` method to know whr `sessions` are stored at your web server.

Look at the `session.save_path` in your `php.ini`.

Comment: in my system's php.ini session.save_path is commented.

Comment: @Sumant mine too .. check this then --<?php echo session_save_path(); ?>