# Session lost in wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress

`pirnt_r($_SESSION)` not print all value.

But we log in wordpress admin and preview page when we write `print_r($_SESSION)` they display all session variable with value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show us the whole code?

Probable cause:

1. try `print_r($_SESSION)` not `pirnt_r($_SESSION);`
2. try to put `echo` before `print_r($_SESSION);` as in `echo print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: soory its my writing mistack i am use print_r($_SESSION) <phpcode>
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
echo $tx_no = $_REQUEST['tx'];
echo $status = $_REQUEST['st'];
echo $amount = $_REQUEST['amt'];
?>
</phpcode>

Comment: Yes try to put `echo print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: i try echo print_r($_SESSION) but nothing. when we work in localhost this print all value in  print_r($_SESSION) but when we update in server that this issue genrat. but we login wordpess admin and priview the page that time display all session variable with value

Comment: session wwork fine when we run page but when we rediredt thay page after payment with paypal that time print_r($_session) not print value its means session lost data any idea about that @ Christian Mark

Comment: Of course, because the server of Paypal is different from your WordPress server. You can't store the session variables to other server like Paypal. According to [Where are $_SESSION variables stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454635/where-are-session-variables-stored), session variables are stored on the Apache server.

Comment: yes we can write code for store value in session in paypal.php file.paypal.php file is put in my theme directory. after we create a page on wordpress and and this paypal.php file select as a template. we access that all variable in localhost but not in server  redirect my site after payment.

Comment: I think for security reasons, all session after redirecting to your site after payment MUST be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress doesn't use session's to log their users in, so if you log in at /wp-admin there are no $_SESSION variables set. Wordpress also doesn't call session_start(). This means you have to start the session yourself if you haven't done so already.

You can do this in the following way:

```
if ( ! session_id() )
    session_start();
```

If you know the session has not been started already you can use just session_start, like so:

```
session_start();
```

If you do this your $_SESSION array should contain the variables you put in it previously.

Answer (score -2):

You can write your question here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/
maybe more helpful

Comment: Put it as a comment to question, not as answer!