# How are HTTP session IDs tracked by the server?

Tags: php, http, cookies

I'm trying a sample on php using:

```
<?php
  $_SESSION["color"] = "blue";
  echo $_SESSION["color"] . ".<br>";
?>
```

When I refresh the page, `blue` is printed but there are no cookies associated with the page I loaded, checking using "Developer Tools". How does the server track my session ID if there are no cookies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are $\_SESSION variables stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454635/where-are-session-variables-stored)

Answer (score 1):

There is a cookie. It's called Session ID. Session ID is a randomly generated string that's given to the client (browser).

The data you assign to a session is stored on server identifiable by session ID.

If you're seeing no cookie stored in your browser, there can be two possibilities:

1. **You're not making a call to `session_start` in your PHP script which is necessary to do at the very beginning of the script.**
2. The browser is not letting cookies to be stored.